# SQL : how to find leaf rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have a self related table myTable like :

```
ID | RefID
----------
 1 | NULL
 2 | 1
 3 | 2
 4 | NULL
 5 | 2
 6 | 5
 7 | 5
 8 | NULL
 9 | 7
```

i need to get leaf rows on any depth

based on the table above, the result must be :

```
ID | RefID
----------
 3 | 2
 4 | NULL
 6 | 5
 8 | NULL
 9 | 7
```

thank you

PS: the depth may vary , here is very small example

[image: Here is a visual demonstration of the sample data]

Comment: You mean "lowest level only of an hierarchy"?

Comment: yes, english is not my native language

Comment: Please update the sample data to show the results when `depth may vary`. Currently you've only asked us to solve the simplest case. If you want the complex case solved also, show it!

Comment: @AaronBertrand i think the sample table contains all the variations, that is one row with no children at all ( ID = 4 ), and another row with a child, which has its own child ( 1 -> 2 -> 3 ).
 I'll try to add some more rows to make it more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT id,
       refid
FROM   mytable t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   mytable
                   WHERE  refid = t.id)
```

Comment: This won't deal with a deep hierarchy

Comment: Can you provide a counter example ? I don't see what won't work.

Comment: See my answer with more data

Comment: The original answer didn't. There was a hardcoded "1". This is 2nd or 3rd edit

Comment: I kindly disagree. The only edits were pageing. Anyway, glad to see this answer's right, I feared I did miss something.

Comment: @X.L.Ant: as per ypercube's comment. I assumed worst case with most complexity

Comment: @gbn I assumed that eventually. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: i had to choose answers between X.L.Ant and @paul.
i chose X.L.Ant because Actual Execution Plan gave me a little bit better results! Thank you X.L.Ant

Comment: @armen: this gives the better plan because of NOT EXISTS. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4010/630 and the follow up links

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int NOT NULL, RefID int NULL);

INSERT @t VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1),  (3, 2),  (5, NULL), 
             (6, 5), (4, NULL), (7, 5), (8, NULL), (9, 8), (10, 7);

WITH CTE AS
(
    -- top level
    SELECT id, RefID, id AS RootId, 0 AS CTELevel FROM @t WHERE REfID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.id, T.RefID, RootId, CTELevel + 1 FROM @t T JOIN CTE ON T.RefID = CTE.id
), Leafs AS
(
    SELECT
        id, RefID, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.RootId ORDER BY CTELevel DESC) AS Rn
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    id, RefID
FROM
    Leafs
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Comment: Recursion is unnecessary for something as simple as this. You just need to check if each rows child have a child of it's own or not. Other two answers are working fine - even with your sample data. This CTE is however missing a row 7,5 ?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic: You are correct, it is too complex. If the hierarchy branches, then you use DENSE_RANK instead. Also, is it the lowest leaf of each branch from a root, or just the lowest for each root?

Comment: @ypercube : can you tell why ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant I retracted my previous comment. Correction: Recursion is necessary if one wants to find all the leaf nodes that are descendants of a specific item. It is not required in this case, where it seems that the OP wants all leaves of the structure.

Comment: @gbn : i need all the leafs, and if there are no, than the root is ok!

Comment: @gbn : your answer refers to my next question that i did not made yet! but the problem here is that i need a pure table as a result, because it is going to be used in a very complex and nested SQL statement like like `select x.* from (select y.* from (select k.* from YOUR_ANSWER_AS_A_TABLE as k) as y) as x` !

Answer (score 3):

```
select  ID, RefId
from    myTable t1 left join myTable t2 on t1.ID = t2.RefID
where   t2.RefID is null
```

Comment: This won't deal with a deep hierarchy

Comment: See comments on the other answers: it depends

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
     my_table
WHERE
     id NOT IN
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT
         refId
      FROM
         my_table
      WHERE
         refId IS NOT NULL
      )
```

Comment: This is very similar to the selected answer. The `exists` approach is preferable. Thank you.